# Integrar WordPress com Oracle

Tags: wordpress, oracle, woocommerce, integração

Vou desenvolver um "E-Commerce" de serviços em WordPress, conhecido como WooCommerce, só que eu preciso integrar ele com o Oracle, além do próprio MySQL que ele irá rodar...

Exemplo: Quando alguém contratar um serviço, preciso que ele mande para meu banco Oracle algumas informações desta compra.

Vocês sabem como posso fazer isso? Existe algum plugin ou vou ter que estudar a arquitetura e eu mesmo fazer minhas adaptações do que eu preciso? Tem outra ferramente que vocês indicam sem ser o próprio WordPress?

Comment: Você quer manter o Mysql pras coisas do WP e gravar algumas informações numa base separada Oracle, é isso?

Comment: Isso mesmo, só quero mandar algumas informações do usuário após ter feito a sua compra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use o hook [`save_post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/) pra isso. Ele roda imediatamente após um post ter sido gravado no banco, e carrega as informações que foram enviadas. Depois você conecta ao Oracle usando [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-oci.php) e segue como se fosse um aplicativo PHP comum:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'enviar_dados_pro_oracle', 10, 3 );
function enviar_dados_pro_oracle( $post_id, $post, $update ) {

    /* faça sua validação aqui, permissões de acesso, nonces, etc */

    if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) )
        return;

    $pdo = new PDO();
    /** todo o resto da sua rotina com PDO aqui */

}
```