# Como faço para exibir as notícias do meu portal antigo com base de dados Oracle ao novo portal com base de dados mysql no Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Saudações, caríssimos!
Estou a criar um portal de notícias com Wordpress e MYSQL e gostaria de recoperar as notícias do portal antigo com base de dados ORACLE.
Não sei, nem por onde começar, para exibir as notícias novas e antigas.
Agradeceria se me puderem ajudar.

Comment: É mais fácil fazer a migração para o `MySQL` ou `MariaDB`. O *WordPress*, por padrão, não tem suporte para o `Oracle`, você até pode fazer uma gambiarra, mas com o tempo a manutenção só tende a piorar. Isso sem contar com os conflitos que você terá com alguns plugins.

Comment: Grande Vladir, isto significa que não tenho como recoperar meus dados do Oracle para exibir no Wordpress? Caso eu tenha de migrar a base de dados do Oracle ao MySQL, qual seria o procedimento e em que ficheiro Wordpress, eu seria obrigado a alter para poder exibir os dados?

Comment: De ter, até tem. Mas não vale a pena o esforço devido o inúmero problemas que você terá futuramente. Nessa resposta, um usuário explica como fazer: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/207721/99718

Comment: Ok! E caso eu queira migrar o Oracle ao MySQL como eu faria, caro Valder para funcionar com o Wordpress?

Comment: Vai depender da estrutura de dados, do tamanho da base de dados. Como não trabalho com `Oracle`, não sei te informar quais os melhores caminho para migração, mas você pode seguir essa resposta: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54413/how-to-migrate-oracle-database-to-mysql-server

Comment: Ok, Grande Valdir. Vou matar a cabeça de modo que eu consiga.

Comment: Olá, Grande Valdeir Psr! Depois de estudar um pouco este conteúdo  pt.stackoverflow.com/a/207721/99718 , pude notar que contrapõe os meus propósitos. Eu não preciso gravar os posts ao Oracle, mas sim recoperá-los. Ou seja, eu estou a criar um novo portal e preciso, além de mostrar os posts actuais que vêm do MySQL, também preciso mostrar os posts antigos que já tenho na BD Oracle.

Comment: add_action( 'save_post', 'enviar_dados_pro_oracle', 10, 3 );
function enviar_dados_pro_oracle( $post_id, $post, $update ) {

    /* faça sua validação aqui, permissões de acesso, nonces, etc */

    if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) )
        return;

    $pdo = new PDO();
    /** todo o resto da sua rotina com PDO aqui */

}                  Conseguimos perceber nas duas primeiras linhas de código que se usou o save_post e o update. Eu pretendo de hook para mostrar os posts, mano. Agradeceria...

Comment: você pode usar o [pre_get_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) para alterar a `query` antes do `wp` capturar os posts ou você pode editar o método `get_posts` da classe `wp-includes/class-wp-query.php` para capturar o registro em outro banco de dados. Posso adicionar um exemplo bem básico, mas já deixo claro que pode prejudicar um pouco a performance do site.

Comment: Graças a Deus consegui solucionar este problema, Grande Valdeir Prs. Apenas, criei um tamplate na pasta raís do tema do meu site e criei uma página seleccionando o meu template criado. Daí brinquei um pouco com o PHP e MySQL que tudo funcionou. Agora, a dúvida consiste em listar as imagens que tenho num directório, mas com nomes guardados na BD. Não estou a ter êxito. Listo tudo menos imagens.